# Serum dex swap error: Error settling funds

Tags: anchor-lang, anchor-client, serum, serum-market

i'm trying to make a serum dex token swap in my program. But the problem is, it only works halfway

here's what I mean:

when I do

```
orderbook.sell(sell_proceeds, None)?;
```

the swap works and the token I'm paying with gets deducted. but when I try to settle funds so I get the quote tokens,

```
orderbook.sell(sell_proceeds, None)?;
orderbook.settle(None)?;
```

the swap gets canceled and the initially deducted funds get returned. Any idea what could be causing this?  (no error is returned from the dex)

by the way, here's the sample repo I'm using

```
https://github.com/project-serum/swap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i was using a wrong decimal to set price for one of the dummy markets I created. everything works perfectly fine now